# How to auto create a dump of a process when a wait chain is stuck for more than x seconds?

Tags: windows, windows-10, process, threads, wait

When a process hangs temporarily and resource monitor/task manager show there is something stuck in the wait chain, I can

1. use for example [Process Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Explorer) to create a dump of it
2. open WinDbg and run `!analyze -v -hang` to see which thread was responsible for >3 seconds  wait chain.

But I can't do it fast enough to catch a dump **while** the short lived wait chain is *waiting*.

I looked at [ProcDump](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) but it doesn't seem to be possible to do an auto dump when a wait chain is stuck for more than 3 seconds.

[WhatIsHang](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/what_is_hang.html) doesn't even list the process I want to monitor (Slack)

In Windows 10 x64 Pro (1607), **how to auto create a dump of a process when a wait chain is stuck for more than x seconds?**

Comment: Are you using the 32- or 64-bit version of WhatIsHang? You may need the 32-bit version if it is a 32-bit process.

Comment: 64 bit process with the 64 bit version of WhatIsHang, but thanks for the heads up @ChrisR.Donnelly !